# How to pass a value on failed validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to pass a value on failed validation in Laravel.

I tried this, but couldn't get the output.

```
if ($validation->fails()) {
   $errorflag=1;
   return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation)->with('errorflag', $errorflag);
}
```

I tried to get this value in the view using just a isset() check

```
<?php 
  if(isset($errorflag)){
      echo $errorflag;
  }
?>
```

But I'm unable to get the output even though I made a validation error in the form. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a flag or session param, `withErrors` fills the variable `$errors` and thus is detectable:

```
@if($errors->any())
   // do something
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

In your blade do

```
@if(Session::has('errorflag'))
//do something
@endif
```

Comment: @ceejayoz:I didn't get you.

Comment: @user1012181 You posted an error message that couldn't possibly have been caused by the code shown. You seem to have deleted that comment.

Comment: ceejayoz was quoting my solution and says that its nice t possible to achieve what you are after with the code i supplied. I say it will pass value from controller to view and will echo that out because that was one of your requirement and I don't believe in spoonfeeding

Comment: @KhanShahrukh No, that's not what I was doing. The OP had posted that your code caused an undefined variable warning, but your code wouldn't do that.